# Any device to move a black hole

Tags: survival, black-holes, escape

Our universe is quite boring area with lot of emptiness. Seems to be a huge misinvestment if the space had a price for the creator (or the causer?). There is almost no way escaping this universe with our existince as solid matter

but

we dont know the rules completely. Lets assume following rules:

- we are living on the surface of 4D universe. The 4th dimension is ofcourse: "the time". We can not leave the surface. The surface is what we call NOW. Also forget about time travel to escape. Just to make thinks easier. We are living on a baloon. If the air around the ballon (call him time-air) blows on you (caused by expansion) the time passes by. The expansion is the time.
- we can trick the time if we move in certain speeds. Just move in any direction, if you move fast enough, the time-air will not get you.
- if the density of ballon is different, you are kind of sitting an a cave on ballon. You can not escape the cave, since this time-air is pressing you down (we call gravity).

i think these assumtions are quite real and no imagination is needed. That s how our universe works.

but

- since the universe is growing (time passes) that means, our universe gonna die and must create another universes. Its very unlikely that we live in THE universe which only exists now and had not precessors and will not have successors. If our universe die, it must create another universes, else the existence has no meaning at all. Or may be it has already created another universes.
- how ever our universe ends, it seems, that we will not get alive out of this armageddon. We have to leave before the crash. Forget about light speeding or worms holes...
- now we know the black holes seem to be good candidates for generating another universes, but they are like falling from the cliff with no surviving changes
- the assumption, that the black holes are the only exit, actually can work in another way. We should not crack the balloon surface to get blow out or in but we might save a piece of balloon for our new universe and burst the old one.
- i think the solution is clear. we need a protection shield made of black holes which will emerge and patch the edges of the ripped off balloon pieces.
- the solution seems to be, that we dont have to move us at all. We have to move black holes and wait that the tension of balloon is high enough and crash them togheter without respect of all other living beeings (compatible to human behaviour)
- i think the rest of exloding universe will emerge to our and the growth will begin again.
- it might hard to accept that we are kind of virus which kill our host and misusing it to survive. But else we will never survive with a mass. There might be another way to sneak our DNA into DNA of universe but this would be another universe.

Can we use anything to move blackholes? It might be that we dont have to need lot of energy but some controlling pulse.

Comment: "we know the black holes seem to be good candidates for generating another universes" They aren't. They're part of our universe, albeit weird ones. Eventually - over timescales so long I won't begin to try to make sense of them - they too will decay into nothingness.

Comment: i meant using them as a shield from exploding balloon. They have to aligned in a spherical form in a far distance

Comment: From your explanation, it looks like you're referring to the Big Rip theory for the death of the universe. I think I can imagine what you want, to be surrounded by blackholes, forming a "force field" of sorts that will prevent anything inside from being ripped apart. But wouldn't black holes merge together, rather than being held in place next to another one?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Andy. I have to say, the number of grammatical and spelling missteps in this post make it hard to read and, thus, understand (which may be the cause of the _unclear what you're asking_ close vote). I would normally [edit] the question to help, but A) I can't take the time at the moment and B) it would be a rather large edit to do without first mentioning it. Additionally, much of the post appears to be irrelevant to the question you want answered, which itself might be better posed to the experts at our [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: Kardashev III civilization should be able to move black holes, either by hoarding a lot of mass to generate a gravitational pull, or finding a way generate gravitation without mass.

Comment: This does not appear to be about worldbuilding, just wildly speculative pseudo-science questions.

Comment: I am afraid I agree with Frostfyre's analysis - if the last paragraph is the "actual question", it could perhaps be massaged to be a worldbuilding question, but is definitely a better fit for physics.se (where the answer will likely be "yes, anything with mass will move it, you just need a LOT of mass, and a way to move that mass ahead of the black hole as it is pulled towards it"). If anything other than the last paragraph is part of the question, then it's unclear what's being asked.

Comment: might be that the post is not about "worldbuilding", may be there is a group for inspirational cosmology

Comment: Black holes can be moved gravitationally and electromagnetically. If you have an electromagnetic field carrying momentum, it can impart that momentum onto the black hole in the same way that infalling matter imparts its momentum.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for this negative sort of answer, but this won't work a bit.

---

First of all, black holes are just as much part of our universe as you and me (Cadence pointed this out before me in a comment). You cannot escape our universe by means of a black hole, even though many soft scifi storing would believe you otherwise. It is true that we don't know whats inside, but whatever it is, it's still fully a part of our universe.

It so happens that the only way that black holes interact with their surrounding is gravity. Thus, the only way that you can move a black hole is by throwing a heavy object at it and have the black hole deflect the path of this object. The black hole will be nudged in the opposite direction.

---

Secondly, and most importantly, you cannot surround a patch of space with a sphere of black holes. Those black holes will merge one by one, forming ever larger black holes until only one is left.

Even if you managed to keep the shell of black holes properly spaced, they will have zero net effect on what's inside the shell: Their gravitational attractions will cancel each other out so that anyone inside will not notice that they are there. Space will be flat inside. *This is for anything inside the shell*.

Again, assuming that you manage to keep the black holes evenly spaced, you cannot fight their mutual attraction. **The shell will be under a huge tension that tries to contract it into a single point, and there is no force in nature that can counteract it.** Thus, the shell will definitely collapse into a single, huge black hole.

Comment: we have no idea how to move a black hole, but once we move them, we could bring them in orbit around our galaxy,

Comment: @Andy Yes, and how do you keep the different orbits of the different black holes from influencing each other? If you have so few black holes that they orbit independently, you have no shell that is any different to the odd black hole careening through our galaxy like any other star does. If you have so many black holes that they could conceivably make a difference, there is no way to arrange them in a sphere of stable orbits.

Answer (score 1):

[There is no universal rest frame of reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20024/31264). Any black will be moving relative to most everything else.

If a black hole is located in a galaxy, for example, it will orbit the galaxy's center of mass.

Perhaps you meant adjusting the holes' orbital paths around whatever. They have mass, so they are affected by gravity like anything else. Just have something massive do a flyby. You'll need to do some boffinry to get the trajectories right. Or you can throw people and stuff you don't like at it to push it by adding momentum.

This will be completely innefective towards achieving your goal of immortality through "baloon patching" though. That may make sense when you're under the effect of psychodelics, but has little to do with modern science's view of the cosmos.

Comment: some psychodelics is not bad for inventing new thinks. we let them orbit our galaxy a couple of millions year. If the end is near, then we can let them fall on galaxy. There might be spherical rip off, instead of common black hole pin-rip off. The target is, living in a black hole without falling into it.